# avoid to receive Broadcast Receiver when app is pause or in background

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I have registered device level Broadcast Receiver ( android.net.wifi.WIFI_STATE_CHANGED), it is working fine to monitor WiFi signal but I want to Lassen Receive class only when app is active or app is not in background or pause state.currently when I leave my app and browse any other App. if I change the wifi signal (close or open) then my Receiver generate event. I want to generate event only when my app is active, I do not want to receive notification in any other App

```
  <receiver android:name="com.android.mobileTimerClock.WifiReceiver"  >
              <intent-filter>

            <action android:name="android.net.wifi.WIFI_STATE_CHANGED"/>
    </intent-filter>
          </receiver>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to register your BroadcastReceiver progamatically on the [Activity.onResume()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onResume%28%29) method, and unregister it on the [Activity.onPause](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onPause%28%29) method.

[Example](http://marakana.com/bookshelf/main_building_blocks_tutorial/registering_broadcast_receiver.html)

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    ...
    // Create the receiver
    receiver = new TimelineReceiver();
    filter = new IntentFilter( UpdaterService.NEW_STATUS_INTENT );
}

protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    super.registerReceiver(receiver, filter,
             "com.marakana.yamba.SEND_TIMELINE_NOTIFICATIONS", null);
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    unregisterReceiver(receiver);
}
```

Comment: but Problem is,i have a lot of Activity ,i can not manage this in Activity level .it should be device level

Comment: Create a BaseActivity which extends Activity and implements this behavior. After that, have all your activities extends BaseActivity instead of Activity.

Comment: thanks,in base Activity ,i am going to override the on pause and on resume.but app is going to exception

Comment: IntentFilter filter =new IntentFilter();
 filter.addAction(WifiManager.WIFI_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION);
  filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF);
  registerReceiver(wReceiver, filter); in my base activity

Comment: public class ScreenReciver extends BroadcastReceiver {
 @Override
 public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {   if(intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF)) {    Intent myintent = new Intent(context,TimerClockActivity.class);
myintent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);     myintent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    context.startActivity(myintent);
         } 
   
  int wifiState = 
         default:
             break;

Comment: there is one big problem ,it is always call wifi change event .screen off does not call

Comment: if i remove  filter.addAction(WifiManager.WIFI_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION); then it will call screen off

Answer (score 1):

I am happy to see  your question.I think you unregisterReceiver() in the onDestroy()  method so that you are receiving the broadcast in background.If you want to avoid it then  unregister  the receiver in onPause().

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    unregisterReceiver(receiver);
}

I hope its help you.
```

Answer (score 0):

Manifest Receivers are intended to process broadcast events even if the base Activity is not active. In fact, you can have a manifest broadcast receiver by itself (without any activity). You cannot use manifest receiver if you dont want your onReceive() to be call based on a particular Activity's state.

However, you still have the option of choosing the way you want to process the event.  You can check if your activity (or activities) are active before you process the event (using ActivityManager).